# MS Access: How do I add the date to the time in this expression?

Tags: datetime, ms-access, expression, ms-access-2013

I need to add the date right next to the time in this expression (within the Design View of a query) so as to make the second part of the `DateDiff` function read: #07/29/2016 08:00:00 AM#

What I have: `DATEDIFF("n", now(), [end_time])`

What I need: `DATEDIFF("n", now(), #7/29/2016# + [end_time])`

What I've tried:

1. `DATEDIFF("n", now(), #7/29/2016# + [end_time])`
2. `DATEDIFF("n", now(), #7/29/2016# & [end_time])`
3. `DATEDIFF("n", now(), Date() + [end_time])`
4. `DATEDIFF("n", now(), Date() & [end_time])`

...but they all return the same error: `This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.`

Comment: Could you explain where the DATEDIFF is done ? Is it in VBA or on a form's field value, or elsewhere ?

Comment: It's in a query (design view).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a column storing a time , and you want to to get the number of minutes from now since that time (Which implies that you are only selecting rows from today). Is that correct ?

Comment: No, the column that stores the time is a future time. It's when the production line will stop, so if it crosses over midnight it could potentially be *tomorrow's* date. But I figured it out, thank you for your time :)

Comment: I was about the propose a  timevalue() but you found it yourself. I just had to udnerstand correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

`DATEDIFF("n", now(), (DateValue(Date()) + TimeValue([end_time])))`

Comment: `Date()` returns just the date part, so applying `DateValue()` is really redundant, but the `TimeValue()` tweak is what I was going to suggest. Thanks for posting your findings.

Comment: Yea I agree that it is redundant, but this seems to get around the error Access is giving. It looks like Access was just being nit-picky if this worked yet the `Date()` alone does not. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) if [end_time] is datetime type

```
DATEDIFF("n", now(), #7/29/2016#) + DATEDIFF("n", #7/29/2016#, [end_time])
```

2) if [end_time] is number (in minutes)

```
DATEDIFF("n", now(), #7/29/2016#) + [end_time]
```